# RewriteRule precedence in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup .htaccess file to rewrite an URL.

**Setup**

Here's my current .htaccess setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews

RewriteRule ^admins/login.html$ mvc.php?rt=admins/login
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ mvc.php?rt=$1&id=$2
```

The idea is to match the `admins/login.html` pattern with the first RewriteRule statement and other `xxxx/xxxx.html` patterns with the second.

**Check result**

To check the result, I simply print the received value on mvc.php

```
echo 'rt = '.$_REQUEST['rt'].', id = '.$_REQUEST['id'];
```

Typing the `admins/login.html` pattern

- my goal: `rt = admins/login, id =`
- what I get: `rt = mvc.php, id = login`

When I comment the second RewriteRule statement, everything works fine.
Is there a precedence in url rewrite rules? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your rules are executing more than once. To stop this behavior have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

# REDIRECT_STATUS is set to 200 after first rule execution
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^admins/login\.html$ mvc.php?rt=admins/login [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```